# Elementary symmetrical polynomial equations, whose solutions are known to be natural numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

Let $n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k$ be natural numbers (excluding 0), and for each $1\leq i\leq k$ let $\sigma_i(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k)$ be the [elementary symmetrical polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) consisting of the sum of all products of $i$ distinct numbers, that is: $$\sigma_i(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k)=
\sum_{1\leq j_1 < j_2 < \ldots < j_i \leq k} n_{j_1}\ldots n_{j_i}.$$

Now, assume you have $k$ natural numbers $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k$, and you know that 
\begin{align*}(-1)^k \sigma_1=a_1,\
&(-1)^{k-1}\sigma_2=a_2,\
&\dots,\
&-\sigma_k=a_k.
&\end{align*}
My question is: Is there a way to obtain (algebraically) the unique set of natural numbers $n_1,n_2,\dots, n_k$ that satisfy these equations? To clearify: The $a_i$ are known, while the only thing we know about the $n_i$ is that they happen to be natural numbers and that they satisfy the above equations.

If I have [understood correctly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial), this is equivalent to asking if there's a way of obtaining (algebraically) the $k$ roots of the polynomial $$ t^k+a_{k}t^{k-1}+\cdots+a_3t^2+a_2t+a_1 ,$$ *knowing* that these roots happen to be natural numbers...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way to find all integer roots of a polynomial is to use the Rational Root Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem . I don't know any way to further use the data that all the roots will be integers.

Comment: @David: The rational root theorem in this case tells us that $q=1$ and that the solutions are factors of $a_1$; but we already knew both of those facts. I also don't know of any way to do better than to try all factors of $a_1$, and I'd be surprised if there were a truly "algebraic" method, since there would have to be some reason why the algebraic formula doesn't extend to arbitrary complex numbers.